# Converting a large square polygon to smaller polygons

Tags: soilgrids

I have a large square polygon and I want to divide smaller polygons this polygon.
I have a large dataset that consists of points inside the polygon.
I want to calculate how many points inside the smaller polygons.

So how can I create a grid and export each gird polygons?

Here is the visualisation on the Google Earth.

Large green square is large polygon polygon. I want to create smaller square polygons like below blue squares and finally my goal is that to calculate how many red point in these blue polygons and sorted largest to smallest.
Below coordinates belong to green polygon.

```
<coordinates>
    29.31234019515055,40.93725819383494,0 29.34257575548109,41.03265424239162,0 29.20971921411221,41.05576636736616,0 29.17179939586544,40.96591648323777,0 29.31234019515055,40.93725819383494,0 
</coordinates>
```

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to show what you have tried. Coding questions here are expected to contain a good-faith effort to solve the problem. It's not clear if you want an even 5x5 grid or something else.

Comment: I haven't started coding. I don't know how to split the polygon into small polygons.
I'm searching algorithm or approach anything that solves this problem. After I found I can code. 

grid size can changeable.

Comment: Don't know why you want to solve it with Python if you have no code yet. There are several approaches without using Python. Just to give you an idea: find intermediate coordinates on the edge of the rectangle. Divide the distance from one vertex to the next one by 5 (if you want a grid of 5 smaller polygons in your bigger rectangle), create new coordinates there that you use to build the small rectangles. Probably not the most elegant way, but simple.

Comment: oh, I think I told wrongly. I searching approach whatever solve it. python is not necessary. It can be a tool to something like that which can be divided small polygons.

Comment: You had tags for PyQGIS and ArcGIS 10.0 but make no mention of using either in the body of your question so I have removed them.

Comment: Create grid, rotate, intersect with your large polygon

Comment: So, the first question is which software will you use it? One idea is use the Fishnet if you have ArcGIS and then fix it it there and see if you can upload it to that site ?